# RIA Services with Silverlight: Having more than 1 domain service?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I was wondering what the pros and cons of OR even if its possible to have more than 1 domain service in RIA Services?

I could separate each domain service i.e. 1 for security, 1 for Products etc

If this possible?

I would love to hear how to go about it.

It seems more logical to have separate domain service classes rather than stick everything in 1 as it would become very unmanageable.

Does anyone know the process for having more than 1 domain service and how to access each one from silverlight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s possible to create more than 1 domain services (i have used it in my projects). 1 for security, and for each entities.
Just create domain service and new instance of domain context in Silverlight.